# Delete fields less than a specific value VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following column in excel

```
Sales Record Number
5100
5275
5310
5355
5357
5359
15
Seller ID: 233
```

I need VBA code to only show the rows greater than the value of 5000 so 'sales record number, '15' & "Seller ID" should be deleted.

I have tried the following:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim i As Long
    For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Not (Range("C" & i).Value < 5000) Then
            Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: it is not removing "seller ID" or "Sales record number" only "15"

Answer (score 0):

An adjustment in the If statement where it first checks if it's numeric or not should do the trick?

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim i As Long
    For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Not IsNumeric(Range("C" & i).Value) Or Range("C" & i).Value < 5000 Then
            Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: yes that worked thanks. If I also wanted to remove an gaps in between the numbers how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Not sure, you should probably post a new question for that where you show a clear example of what you need.

Comment: sorry meant *any gaps. basically sometimes there may be a gap between the numbers which i would like to remove the row where the gap is.

Comment: You mean a row with a blank cell? The code above seems to remove that already. Show an example of the problem in a new question if you mean something else.